# sed command works in terminal but not through bash_aliases or a bash script

Tags: command-line, bash

Every time Vivaldi gets updated, I have to run this sed command to apply custom.css

```
sudo sed -i '1s/^/@import "custom.css";/' /opt/vivaldi-snapshot/resources/vivaldi/style/common.css
```

Now the command works fine in the terminal but not when I try to run it by creating an alias in ~/.bash_aliases or even through a bash script (placed inside /bin/ with executable permission). I did try using full-path for "custom.css" but it still didn't work. Thanks.

Edit:

(1) Through alias:

```
alias vivupdate="sed -i '1s/^/@import "custom.css";/' /opt/vivaldi-snapshot/resources/vivaldi/style/common.css"
```

When I tried to run, I'm getting this error:

```
$ sudo vivupdate
[sudo] password for admn:

sudo: vivupdate: command not found
$
```

(2) Through a Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -i '1s/^/@import "custom.css";/' /opt/vivaldi-snapshot/resources/vivaldi/style/common.css
```

created vivupdate.sh, made it executable and placed it inside /bin/.

Then edited sudoers file and added:

```
user ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/vivupdate.sh
```

But when I run the script in terminal, I get this error:

```
sed: couldn't open temporary file /opt/vivaldi-snapshot/resources/vivaldi/style/sedCIt48u: Permission denied
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the bash script and the alias and how you tried to run them.

Comment: Yes, we can't help you debug a command if you don't show us the command. Also, please explain what you mean by "didn't work". Was `common.css` not modified? Was it modified but the change was ignored? Was it modified in a different way to what you were expecting? What happens when you try the alias? Any error messages?

Comment: @terdon Ok, I have just added the details on (1) alias and (2) script with errors I'm getting. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aliases aren't available to `sudo`. They are specific to your shell and user, and `sudo` is running commands as root. Therefore, if you need an alias to be run as root, you need to include the `sudo` in the alias definition itself. Also, you have the quoting wrong on the alias there, so it wouldn't work anyway. What you want is:

```
alias vivupdate="sudo sed -i '1s/^/@import \"custom.css\";/' /opt/vivaldi-snapshot/resources/vivaldi/style/common.css"
```

Note how I escaped the inner double quotes (`\"`). Without that, since you are defining the alias with double quotes, the second double quote (the one before `"custom.css`) will signify the end.

---

The issue with the script is because of how `sed -i` behaves. Although it seems to be editing the original file, what actually happens is that it saves the edited file as a temporary copy and then renames the file back to the original. However, since you're not running it with `sudo`, you don't have permission to do so. The line you added to the `sudoers` file only means you can run `sudo vivupdate.sh` without a password. However, you still need to run it as `sudo`.

It isn't enough to add the command to `sudoers`, you still need to call it with `sudo`:

```
sudo /bin/vivupdate.sh
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for the detailed reply.